# Suma de array con fórmula

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código que tengo hasta el momento

```
var arrText = new Array();
var arrText2 = new Array();

$("#disSanitary").find("input").map(function () {
    arrText.push($(this).val());
    arrText2.push($(this).val());
});

/*Convertir de string a entero*/
for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {

    arrText[i] = parseInt(arrText[i], 10);
    arrText2[i] = parseInt(arrText2[i], 10);
}

//Poner baños
var distancia, aux = 0;

for (var i =  0; i < arrText.length; i++) {

    parseFloat(arrText[i]);
    distancia = (arrText[i] + aux) / escala;
    aux = aux + arrText[i];
    var altos = 68;
    var disxd = (aux - 250) / escala;
    var image = document.getElementById('screem');
    ctx.drawImage(image, 80 + disxd, 67);

}

//Calcular centro de sanitarios y poner valor.
arrText2.splice(0,1);

//Centro de sanitarios
var distanciaCentro, aux8 = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {

    parseFloat(arrText[i]);

    if (i === 0) {
        distanciaCentro = arrText[i] + (arrText2[i]) / 2
    } else {
        if (i => 1) {
          distanciaCentro = arrText[i] / 2 + (arrText2[i]) / 2
        }
    }

    //aux8 = aux8 + arrText[i];
    /*Info Ancho cubículo individual*/
    ctx.font = '15px Arial';
    ctx.fillText(distanciaCentro, 95 + disxd, 120);
}
```

El `for` que se llama *Poner baños* es el encargado de ponerme los sanitarios como se muestra en la imagen.

El `for` que se llama **Calcular centro de sanitarios y poner valor**. Lo que me toca hacer es calculcular y poner el valor que me dé en el centro de los sanitarios. La fórmula es la siguiente, tengo 3 inputs los culaes tienen un valor de `420, 900, 900` respectivamente.

el primero centro se calcula así:

```
420 + 900 / 2 = 870
```

los otros valores se calculan así:

```
900 / 2 + 900 / 2 = 900.
```

y el último centro de sanitario se calcula así:

```
2650 - 870 - 900 = 880
```

donde `2650` es el ancho total que se puede ver en la imagen.

Por último, aquí se muetran solo 3 inputs, pero puede llegar hasta 10 inputs, por lo tanto no sé cómo aplicar la fórmula.

Comment: Creo que esa es una regla de negocio, a mi punto de vista, el analista es el que debe de explicarte la fórmula que se va a usar.

Comment: Considerando el dicho"una imagen dice mas que mil palabras" al colocar imágenes se debe incluir un "resumen" de esas mil palabras. Lo que quiero decir es que deberías indicar al menos el sentido de incluir cada imagen o lo que se quiere que el lector observe. En cuanto al comentario previo, me parece que se debe debido a lo mismo, lo cual se puede sintetizar como "no está claro lo que se pregunta".

Comment: Te podrías explicar a qué te refieres con centros. Podrías marcar en la imagen las distancias 420, 900, y 900 así como los centros para tener una visión más exacta de lo que pretendes? Tu objeto image es sólo el sanitario o incluye los muros?

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la fórmula que planteas, noto que ya lo tienes casi al 99% en tu código (solamente te falta calcular el valor final). Según tu descripción para hallar los centros de los sanitarios debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Si se trata del primer elemento el cálculo será: `primer elemento + la mitad del segundo`
- Si se trata del último elemento el cálculo será: `ancho total - sumatoria de los valores calculados anteriormente`
- En el resto de los casos el cálculo será: `promedio de (elemento actual + elemento siguiente)`

  Por lo tanto, simplificando tu código he creado esta función a la que le envías un `array` con los valores de los inputs y el ancho total y te devolverá otro `array` con los centros calculados:

```js
function getCentros (array, ancho) {

  var sum = 0;

  return array.map(function (num, index) {

    var result;

    switch (index) {

      case array.length - 1:
        result = ancho - sum;
        break;

      case 0:
        result = num + array[index + 1] / 2;
        break;

      default:
        result = (num + array[index + 1]) / 2;

    }

    sum += result;

    return result;

  });

}

console.log( getCentros([420, 900, 900], 2650) );
console.log( getCentros([100, 840, 750, 560, 900], 3560) );
```

En cuanto a obtener el `array` de valores de los inputs, no tienes que crear dos `arrays` ni tienes que hacer el código tan complicado, el siguiente ejemplo crea un `array` de valores numéricos tomando como referencia el valor de los inputs. (Este `array` sería el que le enviarías a la función `getCentros`).

```js
var array = $("input").toArray().map(function (item) {
    return +item.value;
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="420" />
<br>
<input type="text" value="900" />
<br>
<input type="text" value="900" />
<br>
<input type="text" value="560" />
```